# Performing a convolution in matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, fft, convolution

Alright, so I am doing some signal processing and I have a signal that is a convolution of a slit of width 83.66 microns and a response function.  I want to use the convolution property of fourier transforms to find the response.  The code I used is as follows:

```
num=xlsread('Data.xlsx','B2:C13');
y=num(13:end);
x=num(1:12);
width = 83.66;
p = width*sqrt(1/(2*pi))*sinc((x)*(width/2));
slit = abs(fftshift(ifft(p)));

figure
subplot(5,1,1);plot(x,y);title('imported data')
subplot(5,1,2);plot(x,p);title('transformed slit')
subplot(5,1,3);plot(x,slit);title('slit')

u = abs(fftshift(ifft(y)));
l = u./p;
response = abs(fftshift(fft(l)));

subplot(5,1,4);plot(x,response);title('response')

%Data Check
check = conv(slit,response,'full');
z = linspace(min(x),max(x),length(check));
subplot(5,1,5);plot(z,check./2);title('check')
```

With x=

> -344.0000 -275.2000 -206.4000 -137.6000  -68.8000         0
>
> Columns 7 through 12
>
> 68.8000  137.6000  206.4000  275.2000  344.0000  412.8000

and y=

```
Columns 1 through 5

       13771       12478       19443       69392      143737

  Columns 6 through 10

      189278      184486      188466      185023      128133

  Columns 11 through 12

       51288       10854
```

So what I do is input the signal, perform the fft.  Then I divide by the sinc function (FT of a slit) and then ifft all of that.  When I reconvolve my response with the slit I have, the two are not the same.

Any ideas or anything that I am clearly doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe since it's just like 20 values, you could post the input data as well?

Comment: As soon as I see `abs` after the first ifft I begin to shudder. Your sinc function is not conjugate symmetric. Post the data with the example for help.

Comment: You are seriously undersampled.  Your spacing in X really needs to be less than half your slit width for this to have any chance of working.  Also, as mentioned by @learnvst, ditch the abs's.  They won't work here.  You have to do the complex multiplication.

Comment: I have the input data posted as x and y.  They are taken directly from the excel spreadsheet