# Rect Function/Square wave in MatLab

Tags: matlab, math, signal-processing, convolution

I am trying to get a square wave of width 83.66.  Seeing as I am using for a deconvolution, I want it to be exact.  Here is what I have so far:

```
width = 83.66;
x = linspace(-400,400,10000);

       a2 =  1.205e+004  ;
       al =  1.778e+005  ;
       b1 =       94.88  ;
       c1 =       224.3  ;
       d =       4.077  ;

measured =  al*exp(-((abs((x-b1)./c1).^d)))+a2;

p = 33*sinc( (x)/(2*width) );
slit = abs(fftshift(ifft(p)));
```

I have a measured fit to my data and want to deconvolve it with my slit of width 83.66.  I tried to build the fourier transform of this and then use `ifft()` but that just gives me a delta function.  It may be a peak with little squiggles at the top, but I do not see it when I zoom in. Plus, my slit should be ~84 wide.

Any ideas on how I can get an accurate representation of the slit.  My other idea was something such as:

```
slit = zeros(length(x))

slit(1:1+width) = 1
```

Comment: Ok, this is a continuation/duplicate of [Performing a Convolution in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17370975/performing-a-convolution-in-matlab), right?  The slit is in the time domain or frequency domain?  What is the amplitude of the slit, 1?

Comment: Yes this is a continuation.  The slit is in time domain.  The amplitude of the slit is indeed one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I would use a `rect` function to set up a slit, like this:

```
x = linspace(-400,400,10000);
width = 83.66;
% create a rect function
rect = @(x) 0.5*(sign(x+0.5) - sign(x-0.5));
% create the time domain slit function
rt = rect(x/83.66);
plot( x, rt);
```

[image: rect]

```
% change it to a causal rect
x0 = width/2 + 20; % move the left edge to be 20 units to the right of the origin
plot( x, rect( (x-x0)/width ) )
```

[image: shift rect]

Comment: Beautiful.  Works exactly how I need it to.

Comment: @JamesMaslek, glad to hear it!  You're problem sounds interesting, I'd love to hear more about it if you have any more trouble!

Comment: Thanks!  I actually do have another question.  I will post it on the forum very shortly.